# How to loading model XML from ros parameter like robot_description in ROS2

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, there. I encountered a problem, I don’t know how to load `xacro` file into gazebo in ros2

In ROS1, we could load model XML from ros parameter

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find m_bot_description)/urdf/mbot_gazebo.xacro'"/>
```

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
args="-urdf -model mrobot -param robot_description"/>
```

And in ROS2, I've found that the ros2 launch have already supported the `command`, maybe I guess the launch file could be written as

[image: image description]

I hope there is an option something like `-param` in the code where I type `-???`, but I only found `-file, -topic, -stdin` in the spawn_entity.py to load the xml

How could I modify it to load the xacro file?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26808/how-to-loading-model-xml-from-ros-parameter-like-robot_description-in-ros2/) by [Jony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46051/jony/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That is a good question:

Looking into the examples, all I can say is that seems like the new approach is using a topic named `robot_description` to load xacro code. See https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control/blob/master/gazebo_ros2_control_demos/launch/cart_example_effort.launch.py#L55. I can not find any other code using parameters.

To complete the information I've updated the gazebo_ros_pkgs migration wiki
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Spawn-and-delete

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46051/jony/) on 2021-04-19**:
Thanks very much