# Gazebo simulation - robot_description param passing

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, gazebo-ros2-control

I'm working on a (simulated) Universal Robot UR10e. I've been able to teleop the robot using a custom controller and it works flawlessly in RViZ. I'd like now to have a reproduction of what happens in RViz (moving the end-effector in space) in Gazebo, so that I can simulate some tasks (pick-and-place).

To do so, in the URDF I've got the following code snippet which loads the controllers config .yaml passed as a parameter:

```
<xacro:if value="$(arg sim_gazebo)">
<!-- Gazebo plugins -->
<gazebo reference="world">
</gazebo>
<gazebo>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
    <parameters>$(arg simulation_controllers)</parameters>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
</xacro:if>
```

I've tried implementing this, starting from the launch file provided by Universal Robots and the robot shows up correctly in Gazebo (and the joint trajectory controller loads fine). However, when I swap the joint trajectory controller with the custom controller (a cartesian one, the same used before), the latter goes into "unconfigured" state and I am not able to use it. In the terminal I can find this error, coming straight from the controller spawner node:

```
robot_description is empty
```

Looking into controller's code, it seems that it's not reading the description from the /robot_description topic: I've found it loads the robot description from the parameters of the spawner node:

```
robot_description = get_node()->get_parameter("robot_description").as_string();
```

As far as I know, [this is going to be deprecated in a few months](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/master/controller_manager/src/controller_manager.cpp#L281C16). [As outlined here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29179/how-to-loading-model-xml-from-ros-parameter-like-robot-description-in-ros2/29180#29180), the only possibility to load a parameter via the spawner is passing a file path, but I can't pass the URDF directly (since it needs to get transformed by the xacro executable before). However, I need to use this controller and I'm looking for a way to pass the robot_description as a param or another way to launch it using the gazebo ros2 control library. Do you know if there is any way to achieve this? Thanks.

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- ROS version: ROS2 Humble
- Robot: Universal Robot UR10e

---

Update w/ solution: I've been able to move the robot in Gazebo Ignition. To do so, I've added a subscription (local transient) into the controller code to the robot_description topic. I don't know if this approach is the right one, but it's working.